# ASP.NET Cookie Not Updating - Environment Specific

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, oauth-2.0, load-balancing

So the code below works in my QA, UAT and PreProd environments, yet the logout doesn't work in prod. Preprod and prod are basically mirror images of each other. The build artifacts promote up through each stage, and the only change that is made is to environmental variables. In all instances, the AppSetting["AuthDomain"] is set to .mydomain.com. Each environment is a subdomain of that parent including prod. The web.config between preprod and prod are the same except for the build number generated from DevOps and pointing at different URLs hosting the UI and API. The prod environment is load balanced so that is the only real difference I can see between preprod and prod.  Authentication is done via oauth2.

Anyone have any thoughts on what might be going on here?

```
// setting cookie
if (auth != null)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie("Token", auth.access_token);
    DateTime expiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(auth.expires_in));
    authCookie.Expires = expiration;
    authCookie.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthDomain"];
    Response.AppendCookie(authCookie);
}

// logout
if (Request.Cookies["Token"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies["Token"];
    authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
    authCookie.Value = null;
    authCookie.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthDomain"];
    Response.AppendCookie(authCookie);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work." As a SWE, I would avoid using that phrase in general. The most common way to describe a problem is to describe the expected behavior and the actual behavior.

Comment: Well doesn't work is doesn't update the expiration of the cookie. You should be able to see that in the logout code block included.

Comment: On the contrary, by looking at your code I can see you are updating the expiration of the cookie. I think what you mean to say is that it is not resulting in an expected behavior of some kind. For example, the cookie header is not being returned to the browser, or it is being returned with an incorrect date, or it is being returned with the correct date but the browser is still presenting the cookie on the next request. I have no way of knowing what behavior you are seeing until you describe it.